# Value Error:Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, valueerror

This code works fine...

```
forest1 = RandomForestClassifier()
forest1.fit(train[['Random Forest Score','lr','neural']],train['target'])
```

But when I try to predict ,

```
test['target'] = forest1.predict_proba(test[['Random Forest Score','lr','neural']])
```

It shows an error..

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Answer (score 3):

[forest1.predict_proba(...)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba) predicts class **probabilities for X**.

It returns an array of shape = `[n_samples, n_classes]`, or a list of n_outputs
such arrays if n_outputs > 1. The class probabilities of the input samples. The order of the classes corresponds to that in the attribute classes_.

`test['target']` expects a vector (1D array)

Try to use [`predict()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict) instead of `predict_proba`:

```
test['target'] = forest1.predict(test[['Random Forest', 'Score','lr','neural']])
```